# fork and pipe bad file descriptor error

Tags: c++, linux, shell

I'm trying to write a basic shell, and in order to facilitate piping, I wrote the following function, where `tokens` is the line to be executed, and `index` is the location in `tokens` of a pipe character (for now, pipes require whitespace on either side). Every time I run a piped command in the shell, both commands run as expected, but fail to write to/read from the pipe with the error "Bad file descriptor". The reason this is perplexing is that my file redirection works perfectly, so I can't understand why it's not working with the pipe. I've read the docs and looked at some example code, and I can't think of anything I'm doing wrong. After a few hours, I'm at a loss, where did I go wrong?

```
int pipeit(vector<string> tokens,unsigned int index){
    //separate the entire line into two delimited by the pipe
    vector<string> firstline;
    vector<string> secondline;
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<tokens.size();i++){
        if(i==index){
            continue;
        }
        else if(i<index){
            firstline.push_back(tokens[i]);
        }
        else{
            secondline.push_back(tokens[i]);
        }
    }

    //make sure the lines aren't empty
    if(secondline.size()==0||firstline.size()==0){
      fprintf(stderr, "ERROR, expected at least one command at both ends of pipe\n");
    }

    //open a pipe, check that it was successfully created
    int pip[2];
    if(pipe(pip)<0){
      perror("pipe failure");
      return -1;
    }

    //attempt to fork
    int parentstatus=0;
    int childstatus=0;
    switch(fork()){

      //fork failed, close the pipe and return -1 (failure)
      case -1:
        {
          close(pip[0]);
          close(pip[1]);
          perror("fork failure");
          return -1;
        }

      //pid of 0 indicates this is the child process
      case 0:
        {
          //close the write end of the pipe and redirect stdin to the read end
          close(pip[0]);
          int stdIn=dup(0);
          dup2(pip[1],0);

          //once redirect is done, can close the other end of the pipe
          close(pip[1]);

          //parse the second line as a list of commands (not important for question)
          //then restore stdin, close the old file descriptor pointing to the pipe
          execute_line(secondline,builtins);
          dup2(stdIn,0);
          close(stdIn);
          break;
        }

      //pid other than 0 indicates this is the parent process
      default:
        {
          //close the read end of the pipe
          close(pip[1]);

          //redirect stdout to the write end of the pipe
          int stdOut=dup(1);
          dup2(pip[0],1);
          close(pip[0]);

          //execute this line (not important for question)
          parentstatus=execute_line(firstline,builtins);

          //restore stdout and close the temporary fd pointing to the pipe
          dup2(stdOut,1);
          close(stdOut);

          //wait for child process to exit and store it's return value in 'status' (then childstatus)
          int status;
          wait(&status);
          childstatus=status;
          break;
        }
    }

    //return a combination of the parent and child's return status
    //(not standard, I know, just easy and irrelevant for the question)
    return childstatus & parentstatus;
  }
```

`tokens` is just a space-delimited `std::vector<string>` that contains the commands to be executed (yeah you need to pad the '|' with spaces for this to work, don't worry about that just yet) and `index` is the place in the list where the '|' character was found, to make things easier. For the purposes of a runnable source file, just paste the above function definition at the bottom of:

```
#include <unistd.h> //pipe, dup2, fork
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int builtins = 0xf00; //not what this actually is, but that doesn't matter atm

using namespace std;

int pipeit(vector<string> tokens, unsigned int index);

void execute_line(vector<string> cmds, int biltins){
    cout << "Executing: " << endl;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < cmds.size(); ++i){
        cout<<cmds[i]<< " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main(){
    vector<string> cmds;
    cmds.push_back(new string("cmd1"));
    cmds.push_back(new string("|"));
    cmds.push_back(new string("cmd2"));
    return pipeit(cmds, 1);
}
```

Comment: You'll get better answers for your code if you tag it `c++`.

Comment: oh yeah I forgot I'm using c++ not just c. Thanks!

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: I'm nut sure what specifically is unclear. I'm trying to implement piping in a shell, I described the error in what I feel is a complete manner and I included the relevant code

Comment: Your code is neither sufficient (it doesn't contain everything needed to reproduce the problem) nor minimal.

Comment: `const char* modeptr=&mode;` is blatantly invalid, btw. `fopen` takes two strings, and `modeptr` isn't one.

Comment: Also, off-by-one error in your `malloc` call (you're overflowing the allocated buffer). And `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition.

Comment: my code cannot be both minimal and functional by nature of the size of the project. It's at least 300 lines to be able to recreate this functionality (or lack thereof), so I included the minimal amount to be able to see what's working and what isn't. Thanks for the malloc thing though, I kept getting corrupt memory issues (just not consistently).

Comment: As for `modeptr` not being passed to `fopen`, I totally am doing that. Are you saying I shouldn't be for some reason? Because it was mad at me for just passing 'r' or 'w'.

Comment: I never said anything about `modeptr` not being passed to `fopen`. I said `modeptr` isn't a string, but `fopen` requires two strings. And your code doesn't have to be functional; it just has to demonstrate the problem you're asking about.

Comment: You mean you want me to try to reproduce the problem in a different program? I guess I can do that, but it still won't be short. and as for 'modeptr', it works when passed that, but not if I pass it 'mode', so I'm not sure what else to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I was reading from the write end of the pipe and writing to the read end. Whenever you use `pipe(my_pipe)`, `my_pipe[0]` is *only* for reading, and `my_pipe[1]` is *only* for writing. This doesn't mean my code works for infinite piping, for anybody else looking this up, but it does single pipes now. 
CTC: IRC user C--